# how do you set the /etc/resolve.conf domain on hirsute server?

Tags: networking, server, dns

I used to be able to address my old server at "dckr1.local", I setup a new hirsute server and change the /etc/hosts lien to read:

```
127.0.0.1 dckr1.local dckr1
```

and added to /etc/resolv.conf

```
search local
domain local
```

but can't get it for the life of me to work when I reboot. resolve.conf gets overwritten. Not sure if by something in systemd or something it's calling like cloud.init.

Comment: Please reboot again, do a `ls /etc/resolve.conf -l` and post the result.

Comment: Have you tried adding: `search: [local]` to your netplan file?

Comment: PS _cloud.init_ is a autoconfiguration tool for using in vm cluster farms. If you don't know what this is, you can disable _cloud.init_.